# Daily updating a database with data from Cassandra

Tags: java, database, cassandra

If I have a Cassandra database on server A and I have a database on server B, which I would like to update with data from my Cassandra database once a day, what are the techniques I should use to accomplish this?

Any discussions I have overheard revolve around picking either HTTP streaming or pagination.

Why do people suggest HTTP streaming or pagination as approaches to do this?
Are there any drawbacks or benefits to picking either?

Comment: Simply? `cron` plus, pick your client, it really doesnt matter, or need to be java, so not sure why you tagged that

Comment: @cricket_007 the reason it matters is because cassandra is a big data database, so you need to consider how to handle transporting that data from one place to another and it needs to be useable via some application so people can use it. Not sure why you suggested cron? How does that solve this problem? I mentioned java because thats the language our applications are written in. Currently anything we do with cassandra is via java and java libraries such as datastax

Comment: "once a day" = cron... I know what Cassandra is, and it's highly available, so it's not really used for "daily batching" anyway. I wasn't aware you need to worry about how applications use it. It's just a CQL query

Comment: @cricket_007 why not something like http streaming or pagination? Where you ask the client to either stream the data to update their db or paginate through the data to update their db? Any discussions i have overheard revolve around picking either http streaming or pagination. Why would you pick cron over these two approaches? Why do people suggest http streaming or pagination as approaches to do this? Are there any drawbacks or benefits to picking either of these over cron?

Comment: You ideally don't stream once a day - streaming is a real time operation. Nor do I think cassandra exposes http streaming, but I could be wrong. Cron doesn't limit you to a technology, it is a scheduler. You can use cron to execute a http stream, or pagination. I was simply pointing out that how you start that process would be scheduled once a day

Comment: @cricket_007 so whether its scheduled once a day or not is not really my concern. I only mentioned that to indicate that i dont want to do this every 5 seconds for live updates. The end goal here is to update an external db once a day with data from our cassandra db. I have heard a lot of people say you should not use streaming for this - but i do not understand why? When you download a file off the internet it is not for live data, yet it uses http streaming. Cassandra does support streaming. The datastax library gives you a stream of type row in Java.The stream can be used with http and REST

Comment: @cricket_007 also, if streaming should not be used for this, what is the recommended approach and why? Thanks for responding by the way - appreciate it

Comment: I just found streaming in the Cassandra wiki, so I was wrong. And you've not mentioned Apache Spark, but that's what I suggest. It doesn't need to be "Spark  streaming", but you get Dataset A, transform and /or dump into database B, which most likely will have a Spark connector

Comment: @cricket_007 do you mind elaborating on why you would pick apache spark over http streaming and pagination?

Comment: First, I don't think cassandra uses http protocol for streaming. Secondly, unless you can stream in chunks, pagination is the only scalable solution. Spark will probably paginate by the primary key. Plus, I like Spark, so I'm biased. However, the bottle neck is the transport mechanism... How will you stream or paginate **into** the other database you've not specified? Is it another Cassandra cluster?

Comment: @cricket_007 so cassandra does not use http, cassandra is just the database, http is the transportation mechanism. With http you can either do streaming or pagination. When cassandra gives you the stream it quietly paginates for you, but the only thing you can set is the fetchsize. You cannot specify the start index. So using http we can either stream the data or use something like solr and paginate through the data. Correct, the transportation bottle neck is where my question is. Why do you suggest that pagination is the only scalable solution? Why isnt streaming scalable here?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not sure if the other database is cassandra or not, the only thing we need to worry about is allowing for a way for the user to get the big data to update whatever database they have on their end. We shouldnt need to later change our api because the user decided to change dbs

Comment: Again, probably wrong, but streaming probably is TCP based, over Thrift protocol, most likely... Anyways, What if the stream dies in the middle? You have to start  from the beginning? If you can't specify the "offsets" to stream by, you have a single point of failure. Whereas pagination, you can specify a start key. Simply a `WHERE x > key`

Comment: Umm, your API is fully dependent upon the other database if you've guaranteed backups from Cassandra to "any service", then you must have a common transport mechanism which does guarantee connectivity. This is often where Spark + Kafka are added

Comment: @cricket_007 okay, thats a very valid point. Are there any other reasons you would use pagination though? Wont pagination be less performant?

Comment: @cricket_007 correct i am looking for a common transport mechanism which is why the discussion is mostly revolving around http streaming and pagination. Http is a common transport protocol. Spark + kafka over http streaming and pagination? What are the benefits of having kafka? Are you suggesting an event based update mechanism?

Comment: Thrift is also a common transport protocol. Unless you can find me a source for http Cassandra connections, then I'm not discussing that... I also can't tell you what pagination or cassandra streaming provides because I've not used them. I've only used Spark with Cassandra and Kafka. And Kafka is definitely a real time technology, but you can always pull daily batches out of that too

Comment: @cricket_007 http has nothing to do woth cassandra or databases. It only has to do with transportation of data. So if i wantes to i can transport data from cassandra using REST with HTTP streaming. Rest and http streaming dont care where the data came from. I have never heard of thrift but i will definitely look that up. Okay, point taken about Kafka. I guess i still dont wuite understanding why not streaming, other than the connection potentially dying (which was a good point) I just feel like there are probably other reasons as well and I dont know what they are :-(

Comment: Cassandra used Thrift before CQL. You don't need REST or HTTP when you can use JDBC. REST endpoint again, is a single point of failure

Comment: @cricket_007 okay, thanks, i will look into Thrift!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my professional opinion, but to recap the comments

> cassandra database on server A and a database on server B

Whatever you write must be able to actually communicate with Server B. Therefore , you're limited to what tools/methods you can use .

> which I would like to update with data from my cassandra database once a day

Long Running batch jobs are not ideal because they can fail at any time and need restarted. Therefore, I recommend a one-off operation on a scheduled service like cron,  Oozie, Airflow, etc.

> http streaming or pagination

Regarding pagination, that's a reasonable solution, but just make sure your client supports it and you can setup multithreading if it's slow.

I personally have no experience with Cassandra and streaming out of it, only into it. And it was using Spark Streaming out of Kafka. I am fairly sure that's binary protocol, but not http. I can't find anything on REST streaming on Cassandra, but it doesn't sound like a good idea to sit your own REST endpoint on top of Cassandra unless you are really skilled at optimizing concurrent operations

Back to the tools/methods, I've mentioned Spark, and I know Cassandra has a nice Spark Connector, so that's my recommendation. If your database B uses JDBC, then you can load data straight from Spark in probably less than 10 lines